# How to make a very long bash command more readable

Tags: bash

Given the following bash command:

```
local output=`tail -n "$TAIL_COUNT" "$LOG_FILE" | tac | ...several other pipe transformations... | grep -Pzo "(?s)(very long pattern1.*){2}very long pattern2"`
```

How do I transform this very long command into a set of shorter multiple lines that fit the width of a normal computer screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write like this:

```
local output=$( tail -n "$TAIL_COUNT" "$LOG_FILE" \
                | tac \
                | ...several other pipe transformations... \
                | grep -Pzo "(?s)(very long pattern1.*){2}very long pattern2" \
              )
```

And if the `grep` pattern is too long I'd save it in a $var.

Comment: If you put the `|` at the ends of the lines, you don't need the ``\``s.

Comment: i like to put `|` at the beginning of continued lines so it's very obvious to me they are pipelines. :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is an idea?

```
local thetail=`tail -n "$TAIL_COUNT" "$LOG_FILE"`
local thetac=`echo "$thetail" | tac`
local theotherpipes=`echo "$thetac" | ...several other pipe transformations...`
local output=`echo "$theotherpipes" | grep -Pzo "(?s)(very long pattern1.*){2}very long pattern2"`
```

Basically just splitting up in variables. This will also help understandability if you give the variables better names than I did.

Another tip: $() is better to execute commands than backticks `. The backticks are considered deprecated and $() will nest where backticks will not.

Answer (score 1):

You can save each command output in a variable and pipe it. Or you can just add backslash (

```
\
```

) after each command.

```
local output=`tail -n "$TAIL_COUNT" "$LOG_FILE" |\ 
tac |\ 
...several other pipe transformations... |\
 grep -Pzo "(?s)(very long pattern1.*){2}very long pattern2"`
```

Comment: There is no need to write \ after `|`. Just remove it and use `|`.

Answer (score 1):

Just add newlines.

```
local output
output=$(
    tail -n "$TAIL_COUNT" "$LOG_FILE" |
    tac |
    ...several other pipe transformations... |
    grep -Pzo "(?s)(very long pattern1.*){2}very long pattern2"
)
```

Nothing you can do with long patterns in grep.

Do not use backticks - use `$(...)` instead. Prefer to use lower case variables. Check your scripts with http://shellcheck.net